# UIWebView: some images not loading

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, image-loading

Good day.

I have a `UIWebView` that loads a big article with 10+ images. HTML code is stored locally, images are loaded by `UIWebView` automatically.

Sometimes web view won't load all of the images (for example, 3 out of 10). It doesn't depend on a connection type `(EDGE/WiFI)`, image amount (sometimes web view loads 20 out of 20 images, sometimes doesn't load 3 out of 5).

As for now the only way to fix this as I understand is parsing `<img>` tags in HTML and loading images programmatically to a local cache for future displaying.

Any thoughts? Is there any way to control `UIWebView's` image loading?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are always the same images that are not loading ?

Comment: Does that happen with both iOS4 and iOS5? Do you have a webserver where you can check the apache logfiles to see if the requests were made at all?

Comment: Yes, it happens on both systems. I'll try to check logs, thank you for a tip.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had the same issue on another project: some images were displaying as half black only on slow connections like GPRS/EDGE. The reason was that my client's web server had a limit for connection time when downloading images. If you've run into similar issue don't forget to check that.

Comment: Do you find the solution to overcome this issue ? Any ideas would be very much helpful. Thanks

Comment: You mean the limit for the connection time? If I recall correctly, it was a matter of increasing the according configuration option on the web server.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the reply